# Configuration in what context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have a root context that have all business bean (it is the root context)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

      <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.mypack">
<context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />    
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

and servlet-context that have only controller bean (it is a child of root)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
      <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

      <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.mypack">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

I want to add a Configuration class in order to create some bean programmatically. My question is: these bean will be part of root-context or servlet-context?

My configuration:

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

     @Bean
     public ArrayList<String> myBean() {
         ArrayList<String> std=new  ArrayList<String>();
         std.add("ciao");
         return std;
     }
 }
```

I ask this because I don't want to create duplicate beans. To not allow this issue if you read my context code the root context have enabled component scan for all components except controller and servlet-context have enabled component scan only for Controller... so my question is the bean ArrayList myBean (declared in my config class) have as context root or servlet-context? Are you sure that spring not create duplicate bean? Please, can you explain the behaviour?

Comment: from my test it seems that configuration bean added is in root container .. can someone explain why ? For my purpose this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The root context have enabled component scan for all components except controller and servlet-context have enabled component scan only for Controller"

AppConfig has Configuration annotation so will be in the root context. As so anything inside that will be in the root context.

Comment: So also Configuration is scanned by context:component-scan .. in this way spring add all the beans contained in all configuration class scanned bycomponent-scan. Can you confirm ?

Comment: only last questo Olga :) : if i create two class @Configuration with some beans Spring in this case add its in root context or i can have only 1 configuration?

Comment: you can have as many configurations classes as you want: http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/modularizing-configurations.html